# Addon or something to automatically click all selected links on page

Tags: firefox, automation, browser-addons, links, mouse-click

Hi,

There is this one page with several links on it and I need to click on some of them. There are way too many and it becomes repetitive and tiresome after a while. I wonder if there is a an addon or something that can automate the process by allowing me to select which links I want to click. For example, all the links that say "delete".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold down the CTRL button when clicking with your mouse. This will open those links in a different Tab allowing you to stay on the current page to keep on clicking. Note that this will eat up you RAM.

I have used the freeware Xenu's Link Sleuth for years now. This is assuming that links are Text based ans not Buttons. You can Choose link's text also.

Comment: sorry but I fail to see how is that going to help save me the effort of clicking all the links if I have to click on them one by one anyway?

Comment: Do you need to see the destination Delete page? Or just clicking on the link is enough?

Comment: well, i need to definy where to click. Because there are many links but I want to click only on some of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Firefox Addons I know of which gets the job done:

1. [Link Gopher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-gopher/)
2. [Bulk URL Opener](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bulkurlopener/)

With 1. you can extract the Links from the page (+ Filter what you want)
With 2. you can open them in new Tabs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).